# How to extract multiple quotes from multiple documents in R?

Tags: r, string, text

I have several Word files containing articles from which I want to extract the strings between quotes. My code works fine if I have one quote per article but if I have more than one R extracts the sentence that separates one quote from the next.

Here is the text from my articles:

> A Bengal tiger named India that went missing in the US state of Texas, has been found unharmed and now transferred to one of the animal shelter in Houston.
> "We got him and he is healthy," said Houston Police Department (HPD) Major Offenders Commander Ron Borza. He went on to say, “I adore tigers”. This is the end.

> A global recovery plan followed and WWF – together with individuals, businesses, communities, governments, and other conservation partners – have worked tirelessly to turn this bold and ambitious conservation goal into reality. “The target catalysed much greater conservation action, which was desperately needed,” says Becci May, senior programme advisor for tigers at WWF-UK.

And this is my code:

```
library(readtext)
library(stringr)

#' folder where you've saved your articles
path <- "articles"

#' reads in anything saved as .docx
mydata <-
  readtext(paste0(path, "\\*.docx")) #' make sure the Word document is saved as .docx

#' remove curly punctuation 
mydata$text <- gsub("/’", "/'", mydata$text, ignore.case = TRUE)
mydata$text <- gsub("[“”]", "\"", gsub("[‘’]", "'", mydata$text))

#' extract the quotes
stringi::stri_extract_all_regex(str = mydata$text, pattern = '(?<=").*?(?=")')
```

The output is:

> [[1]]
> [1] "We got him and he is healthy,"
> [2] " said Houston Police Department (HPD) Major Offenders Commander Ron Borza. He went on to say, "
> [3] "I adore tigers"

> [[2]]
> [1] "The target catalysed much greater conservation action, which was desperately needed,"

You can see that the second element of the first output is incorrect. I don't want to include

> " said Houston Police Department (HPD) Major Offenders Commander Ron
> Borza. He went on to say, "

Answer (score 0):

Well, technically the second element of the first output is within quotes so the code is working correctly as per the pattern used. A quick fix would be to remove every 2nd entry from the list.

```
sapply(
        stringi::stri_extract_all_regex(str = text, pattern = '(?<=").*?(?=")'), 
        `[`, c(TRUE, FALSE)
       )

#[[1]]
#[1] "We got him and he is healthy," "I adore tigers"               

#[[2]]
#[1] "The target catalysed much greater conservation action, which was desperately needed,"
```

Comment: Thanks for that. That'll prove to be awkward for a full data set. Seems like I'd need to identify quotation marks that start a quote and those that end a quote

Answer (score 0):

We can do this with `base R`

```
sapply(regmatches(text, gregexpr('(?<=")[^"]+)', text, perl = TRUE)), function(x) x[c(TRUE, FALSE)])
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting an error when I run the code `Error in gregexpr("(?<=\")[^\"]+)", mydata$text) :   invalid regular expression, reason 'Invalid regexp'`. This may be from how I'm inputting the text. I have a `mydata` object which is of class `readtext` and the column `text` contains the text for each article, this column is of class `character`.

Comment: @adkane sorry, forgot `perl = TRUE` updated